# Rhythmbox: How to delete or disable the Online Resources "Radio France" and "Jamendo"?

Tags: configuration, rhythmbox, plugins, extension

Is there a way to delete or disable the Online Resources "Radio France" and "Jamendo" in Rhythmbox?
[The Jamendo plugin seems to no longer exist.](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654637#c2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > Plugins: Disable "**Grilo media browser**".
This removes the Online Resources "Radio France" and "Jamendo".